# What will imageLoad() function return if the format qualifier is r32f in GLSL?

Tags: opengl

I know if set the format qualifier `rgba32f`,when call `imageLoad()`,I get a vec4. If I set format qualifier `r16ui`, what will I get? Wiki specifies the funcion still returns a four component value, what exactly each component of the value is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll get 0,0,1 for the other three components.

This is what the spec says:

> ## Texture Image Loads and Stores
>
> ... Loads always return a value as a `vec4`, `ivec4`, or `uvec4`, ... Data are
> converted to/from the specified format according to the process
> described for a TexImage2D or GetTexImage command
> ... **Unused
> components are filled in with (0,0,0,1)** (where 0 and 1 are
> either floating-point or integer values, depending on the format).

Comment: Thanks a lot.If so,the first component will be the value in texture ,but the format is r16ui,and short isn't supported by GLSL,will it be transformed to 32 bit integer?

Comment: `r16ui` is a *uint-image-format-qualifier*, so you must use it with a `uimage` type and the corresponding value from `imageLoad` will be a `uvec4`.

Comment: I have test this function,and if I call `imageStore`,opengl will only store the first component, with format qualifier `r16ui` or other single component format.

Comment: @Chris: (a) your question was about `imageLoad`. (b) what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Oh,I know,and I just did some extra test.